# Insert text from C# into webview - UWP

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, uwp

I am currently working on an app where i use a webview to display a webapp. I want to make it so that a user does not have to type his username everytime he starts the app . I want to automatically fill the textbox in the webview with text from c#. I have the following code untill now but I think my javascript is far from good (I don't have any specific knowledge about javascript).

```
 private async void asyncjevoordeuser()
    {
        var inputValue = "test";

        var functionString = string.Format(@"document.getElementById('username');", inputValue);
        await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });

    }
```

I am calling this method from

```
     private void WebView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
  {
      asyncjevoordeuser();
    }
```

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: What is the value of ‘functionString’? Have you checked?

Comment: Does the TextBox get populated or not?

Answer (score 3):

```
await WebViewObj.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('username').value = 'username here';" });
```